# Dúvida sobre o echo dentro de um loop

Tags: php, loop, echo

tenho esse código para um teste de API e queria que a cada final de loop ele escrevesse na tela o progresso do script em %, mas ele só mostra quando termina de fazer tudo, tem algum jeito de fazer isso funcionar ? .

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//url do destino da requsiçao, equivalente ao "action" de um formulário
$url = 'localhost:8000/api/aluno/register';
// Faker
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();
$resultados = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
//estes seriam os "inputs" do formulário
$campos = array(
  'nome'=>urlencode($faker->name),
    'telefone'=>urlencode("4321"),
  'objetivo'=>urlencode("Ficar Monstro"),
    'email'=>urlencode($faker->email),
    'endereco'=>urlencode($faker->address),
  'numero'=>urlencode($faker->numberBetween(1,800)),
  'bairro'=>urlencode($faker->city),
  'nascimento'=>urlencode($faker->dateTimeThisCentury->format('Y-m-d')),
  'vencimento'=>urlencode($faker->numberBetween(1,28)),
  'imgName'=>urlencode("default.png"),
  'status'=>urlencode("ativo"),
  'password'=>urlencode($faker->password),
  'status_mensalidade'=>urlencode("Pago"),
  'atividade_id'=>urlencode($faker->numberBetween(1,8)),
  'tipo_atividade'=>urlencode("Individual"),
  'valorPago'=>$faker->numberBetween(1,40),
);
// Header
$header     =   array();
$header[]   =   'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$header[]   =   'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAvYXBpL2F1dGgvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTY0MTA0NDgsImV4cCI6MTUxNjQ0MDQ0OCwibmJmIjoxNTE2NDEwNDQ4LCJqdGkiOiIySHNzS3BDb1Z5cnRLcDlGIiwic3ViIjo0MCwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.AWaghE64hQv-iix6Lmd2id7d669MfKeA1tot_GN2kUU';
//temos que colocar os parâmetros do post no estilo de uma query string
$string_campos = null;
foreach($campos as $name => $valor) {
    $string_campos .= $name . '=' . $valor . '&';
}
$string_campos = rtrim($string_campos,'&');
$ch = curl_init();
//configurando as opções da conexão curl
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//este parâmetro diz que queremos resgatar o retorno da requisição
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($campos));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string_campos);
//manda a requisição post
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $i/200 . '%';
array_push($resultados,$resultado);
}
var_dump($resultados);
?>
```

Comment: No asp clássico eu usava um flush, deve ter algo parecido para o php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função [**ob_flush**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-flush.php)/[**flush**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.flush.php) para descarregar o `buffer` de saída.

```
<?php

echo "aaaa, ";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5); //Espera 5 segundos

echo "bbb!";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5);

echo "cc!";
```

Comment: Não funcionou .-.

Comment: Agora foi, obrigado =)