# Problema com retorno usando flush() no php

Tags: php

É meu primeiro posto aqui no site.
Estou com um problema que não sei como resolver. Não sei se é uma limitação do meu servidor...

Gostaria que esse código abaixo retornasse um número após o outro no intervalo de um segundo, porém no meu servidor a página fica em branco e quando termina vem tudo de uma vez. No outro servidor funciona como quero.

```
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
```

Gravei um vídeo explicando o problema.

**[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxdDd-0O7ng)**

---

Nesse servidor funciona como eu queria que fosse: 
**http://ronaldoguedes.com.br/p3.php**

Nesse que o que que preciso **não funciona**: 
**https://wistats.com.br/main/p3.php**

Uso *NGINX* numa instancia do servidor LINODE com 1GB de RAM e 1 núcleo. Será que é isso? Limitação do servidor?

Comment: Tenta dessa forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270638/99718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A provável causa é o buffer de saída do NGINX.

Você pode, desabilitar o proxy no arquivo de configuração:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Ou tentar desabilitar via reader no seu código:

```
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

Referencia: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_buffering

Comment: Obrigado Gustavo.... sua solução deu certo!!  consegui usando o header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

Porem gostaria de usar a opção acima pra ficar em todas as paginas.  proxy_buffering off;

Sabe qual arquivo devo encontrar essa linha pra mudar pra off?

Comment: Você coloca no arquivo nginx.conf, logo abaixo do 
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_buffering off;
}
provavelmente em /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf ou /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Obrigado Gustavo... deu certo! Obrgiado mesmo.. ficou exatamente como eu queria... traz alguma vantagem eu colocar esse codigo na instancia do banco de dados que tenho? e em outra instancia apenas para tarefas cron?

Comment: Bah, não sei... bateu no meu limite. :)

Comment: sem problemas.. ja ajudou demais ... obrigadoooooooo