# PHP - Dividir lista e imprimir

Tags: php, foreach, for

Estou criando um script para estudo e 
preciso dividir a lista em array. Para que possa ser informada em for ou foreach.

Que em cada conta testada é informado o resultado na tela e assim em diante...

Estou utlizando um script em for que só imprime na tela quando todas as contas é testada..

Script:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
        $lista = $_POST['emails'];

        $linha = explode("\n", $lista);
        $size = count($linha) -1;

        for($i=0;$i<=$size;$i++){
            $conta = explode("|", $linha[$i]);
            $email = $conta[0];
            $senha = $conta[1];

            $a = new cURL;
        }
    }
```

Lista de exemplo:

### [image: Minha lista]

Comment: Seria isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270638/99718 ?

Comment: Assim mesmo! Obrigado

Comment: Aconteceu um novo erro.Sempre que testo mais de 1 unidade o resultado sai errado. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Como assim “errado”?

Comment: As contas que deveriam sair com o resultado "aprovado" estão saindo "reprovado" e vice e versa. Porem quando colocar 1 unidade o resultado sai correto

Comment: De onde vez esse "aprovado"? Se possível posta parte do código que dê para testar, assim fica mais fácil entender.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288300/php-erro-for-e-function